# 録音した音声をplistファイルに保存する方法がわかりません

Tags: swift

音声を録音（.wav）するアプリを作成しているのですが、録音が完了した際に、プロパティリスト(plist)へ保存する方法がわかりません。
録音したものを保存する方法がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけるとありがたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 音声ファイル本体は、Documentsフォルダに保存し、そのファイルパスをプロパティリストに保存するというのが、現実的ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
音声ファイルをバイナリ化して、プロパティリストに保存するというのは非効率的でしょうか？

Comment: 私は効率性の話をしているわけじゃありません。そんなこと考える気もありません。ただ、こちらからの問いかけに、「No」とお答えするのなら、そこで対話は終わり。こちらからは「ではさようなら」と対話を終わらせるだけです。さようなら。

Comment: @Harawo 効率性の話というか、「音声ファイル本体は、Documentsフォルダに保存し、そのファイルパスをプロパティリストに保存する」という別のアプローチを提示されたので、plistに保存するのが現実的でない理由を聞いているのだと思います。なぜその方が現実的だとお考えになったのですか？

Comment: @unarist ファイルパスは、形式としてテキストかNSURLなので、プロパティリストに保存するのに、特別な技術は不用。質問者さんの別質問で、録音した音声ファイルを、キャッシュフォルダに保存するコードを書かれているので、音声データからファイルを作成し、保存することは、質問者さんはすでにできている。以上の2点から、現在の質問者さんの技術で、可能な方法ということで、「現実的」と表現いたしました。